# Appium for testing mobile app for call and video meeting like Zoom

Tags: android, appium, adb, appium-android, appium-ios

I have to implement framework for iOS and Android device for testing app like Zoom, where I have to test call and video functionalities are working fine. However, for this I need to play audio and video stream when user is in-meetig, which makes the mic and video elements to change the elements and I needs to verify this elements, which is possible to validate only when mic and video are in use when in call.

Looking for some help where I can send adb command which play audio stream using device mic and command to play video stream using device camera, which behaves like real user is on video call with other participants.

Is this requirement is possible to implements with Appium?

I am using ruby, with cucumber for Android and iOS device

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this thread](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/191779/stream-audio-from-pc-to-android-7-over-usb-without-creating-a-local-network)?

Comment: Thanks for the link, that will help me!!!